# How to reference dynamically a cell on another sheet in libreoffice?

Tags: reference, libreoffice-calc

In LibreOffice Calc I want to reference a sheet and a cell depending on the values in other cells. For example with

```
=INDIRECT(C$3 & ".D24")
```

I can reference the sheet, depending on the value of `C3` and there the cell `D24`. That works quite well, but the cell is hardwritten here. I would like do have a *reference cell* for `D` and maybe for `24` as well. But the 24 could also be dynamically changed like calc usually does when the $ lock sign isn't used.

I tried:

```
=INDIRECT(C$3 & CONCATENATE(C1; ROW()))
```

which is not working unfortunately... `C1` value is `D` in this example

Answer (score 2):

ok cool I got it by using

```
=INDIRECT(C$3 & CONCATENATE(".";$C$1;ROW()))
```

- `C3` value is the name of the other sheet
- `C1` value is `D` for the
  column on the other sheet

Answer (score 0):

For `24` as well (say in C2), maybe:

```
=INDIRECT(C$3&"."&C$1&C$2+ROW()-3)
```

if to copy down, assuming result is to be in Row3 (or adjust offset).